# How to pass Parameters in command task in IICS

Tags: linux, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, iics-di

How do I pass parameters to command task in IICS Informatica? CMD task is the only task in our task flow. We are calling Linux script in cmd task.

I want that everything in Linux script which we are calling from command task like folder path ,prefix etc , i want to parameterized everything.

Answer (score 0):

The Command Task has following Input Fields available:

- Script Name
- Input Arguments

Put the script name in the first one and change the latter to `Formula` and put the name of the parameter having the values for the arguments.